# Como é a separação projeto java?

Tags: java

Bom, venho do .net e lá temos projetos que podemos dividi-los em class library e web project

Tenho meu projeto apenas para meus models
Outro projeto só de utils
e meu projeto apenas web

No Java como é feita essa separação? Tentei procurar algum projeto opensource java web para ver como é a estrutura de projeto

Alguém pode me explicar e se possível me falar um médio/grande projeto opensource em java web(indiferente do framework)

Comment: o que são `models` e `utils`? não sei nada de c#

Comment: MVC - M (Models) classes de negócio, utils é só classes para auxilio, segurança, gerar xml ou algo que você precise, rs

Comment: Dica: Você pode usar o MAVEN. Sua estrutura de projeto poderá ser usada em N IDEs. Ele serve para Projeto Desktop e Web, muito prático e simples de usar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma coisa é a divisão em projetos feita por IDEs como Eclipse e Netbeans e outra coisa é a divisão do Java em bibliotecas.

Um programa Java carrega dinamicamente classes e recursos que estão disponíveis no `classpath`, que pode ser definido como parâmetro e consiste numa lista de diretórios e arquivos Jar. Jar é basicamente um zip com classes compiladas dentro. Então, basicamente você pode plugar qualquer dependência colocando classes ou jars em algum diretório incluído no `classpath`.

Quanto à organização para desenvolvimento, em geral você pode criar projetos de vários tipos nas IDEs: bibliotecas e programas desktop (jar), web (war), enterprise com EJB (ear). Para definir quais projetos dependem de qual, cada IDE possui seus mecanismos, mas note que isso é apenas uma configuração lógica para a compilação, pois como já descrito acima, na prática, todas as classes enxergam todas.

---

**Atualização**

Como mencionado nos comentários, existem ferramentas de *build* como o Maven que permitem a você configurar os diferentes projetos, suas dependências, os artefatos gerados, enfim, todo o ciclo de geração.

É uma forma mais genérica e agnóstica de organizar os projetos. Eu recomendo fortemente porque também facilita a integração em ferramentas de Integração Contínua, análise estática de código, geradores de código, etc.

No entanto, ainda assim isso não é algo intrínseco do Java, mas uma organização lógica de projetos.

Comment: Ou pode-se "ignorar" a organização da IDE, que pode ser algo específico de cada uma delas e utilizar o [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) .

Comment: @RicardoGiaviti Obrigado pela dica, eu havia pendo sobre isso, mas tive que ir para uma reunião e acabei publicando a resposta sem falar do Maven. Mas realmente é importante comentar, então atualizei a resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode separar seu projeto em módulos.

Neste post o Eder Magalhães mostra como fazer isso usando o Maven.

http://www.yaw.com.br/screencast/show/maven-multi-module/